# What is the best strategy to upgrade a project in Ember CLI?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Ember CLI and Ember.js have some build time issues in older versions. One often mentioned solution is to upgrade stack to new versions. It means updating whole stack.

What is the best strategy to upgrade it to not destroy the whole project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ember-cli-update](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-update). The README includes instructions on how to use both the global npm package version as well as the addon version.
It also has an option to run codemods, to easy upgrading.

I recommend moving from LTS to LTS at a maximum, because you are likely to surface deprecations in your project's dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Just follow the instructions for the release you want to upgrade to at: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases

Depending on how far behind you are, you may want to upgrade incrementally.

Always commit your changes when everything is working, so you have a restore point in case something goes awry.

After you are done upgrading Ember, you will probably want to upgrade your dependencies.  I suggest using `yarn upgrade-interactive` and `yarn outdated` to see if there is anything newer you want to upgrade to that exceeds the versions specified in your `package.json`.

You could try upgrading everything at once, but you may need to upgrade packages one-by-one if you run into trouble.  I usually do this:  upgrade everything, hope for no problems.  If there are problems, then I reset to the last stable commit.  Then I upgrade only the packages that I think are low risk at one time, and then upgrade the riskier packages one-by-one.  The reason is that sometimes when you are upgrading multiple packages at the same time, and you have test failures, it can be difficult to determine what package caused the problem.